# React: Reloading the page doesn't fetch the data anymore

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components

When I am on my home page and click on a "lesson" component, the lesson page loads, takes the id of the lesson from the url and gets the data (from a local js file) to populate the lesson page. Well, that only happens when I click from the home page. But when I'm already on the lesson page with the data populated and I reload the page, I takes the id from the url but this time the data appear "undefined"... I don't understand why it doesn't take the data as previously?

Here is my component implementation:

```js
 const Lesson = () => {
  const { id } = useParams();
  const [lesson, setLesson] = useState(getLesson(id));

  console.log("id: ", id);
  console.log("lesson: ", lesson);

  return (...);
};
```

Here is the console when I click on my lesson component from the home page:
[the console when it works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ZcDL.png)

There is the console when I simply reload the lesson page: [the console when it doesn't work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ucu8h.png)

I tried using useEffect() with a setLesson(getLesson(id)) inside but nothing changed...

I also tried this:

```js
 if (id) lesson = getLesson(id);
```

But again, it didn't work... :(

getLesson() gets its data from this file called fakeLessonsService.js:

```js
 import getHipHopLessons from "./hipHopLessons";

 const lessons = [...getHipHopLessons()];

 export function getLesson(lessonId) {
    return lessons.find((lesson) => lesson._id === lessonId);
 }
```

The file "./hipHopLessons" simply returns an array of lesson objects.

getLesson() is only loaded on this page.

Comment: Where is `getLesson` getting its data from? Has it been loaded before you call `getLesson` when you load the lesson page?

Comment: I edited my post. Feel free to ask more questions if you need.

Answer (score 0):

The argument to useState is only used on initial render.

You should use a useEffect to update the state if the id changes

```
const [lesson, setLesson] = useState({});

useEffect(() => {
   getLesson(id).then(val => setLesson(val));

}, [id]);
```

PS. Make sure `getHipHopLessons` is not asynchronous

If it is async, then you must write the code like

```
import getHipHopLessons from "./hipHopLessons";

 export async function getLesson(lessonId) {
    const lessons = getHipHopLessons();
    return lessons.find((lesson) => lesson._id === lessonId);
 }
```

Comment: You meant: 
`const [lesson, setLesson] = useState({});

 useEffect(() => {
    setLesson(getLesson(id));
 }, [id]);` ? I tried your code and the one just here but both return "undefined" as usual :/

Comment: Did you make sure that `getHipHopLessons` isn't async

Comment: I don't know how to do it but this app will be deployed on heroku later so it will be async anyway. Should my code work in async even if it's local since I'm gonna deploy it on heroku later?

Comment: I tried your code with the async decoration and I got the same behavior. From the home page, it works but when I reload the lesson page I got "[[PromiseStatus]]: "resolved" [[PromiseValue]]: undefined" in the console :/ I'm only begining to learn back-end so I don't really understand how I can get a resolved promise but no data..

Comment: Since the data is fetch in async, it should be updated in state like `getLesson(id).then(val => setLesson(val));`